# How to open a cashdrawer in android, using USB connected printer?

Tags: usb, thermal-printer, point-of-sale

We have a Point of Sale Application in that, iam using bluetooth, USB printer for receipt printing, through bluetooth option when i eject cashdrawer its working fine and iam using printer.printFormattedTextAndOpenCashBox(text, 40),
When coming to USB printing, got the printing, but unable to open the cashdrawer, i didnt found any methods like above for USB.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's bluetooth/USB or not, it's compatible with whether the printer has the ability to connect and open a CashDrawer and support commands to open the CashDrawer sent by your library or API. Is it there? It will be difficult to get advice and answers because there is no information to look up from the question content. Please add information such as the printer vendor and model and what library/SDK/API you are using.

Comment: Did you find out any solution to open cash drawer in USB printing? It would be appreciable if you share the solution.